# check the "unblock" in file properties for a xml file

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, permissions

I have a firefox imacro script that downloads a xml file from a trusted source. When the file is downloaded we process the file using ssis. Unfortunately we can not do this unless the "unblock" button is clicked in the file properties, next to the message "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer".

My question is how do I write a script to set the attribute to "unblock"? Can someone advise on what is the name of this attibute so I can further research

config info: 
- win 2003 std R2 -sp2 server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is stored in an [alternate NTFS stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_.28ADS.29) named `Zone.Identifier`, attached to the file.

You can view the data inside by, for example, running `notepad foo.xml:Zone.Identifier`

[SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) has a tool **[Streams](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx)** for removing NTFS streams. Download it and run:

```
streams -d foo.xml
```

*(Or you can write your own, consisting of a single `unlink("foo.xml:Zone.Identifier");`)*